# Understanding Gradle's mavenDeployer

Tags: groovy, gradle

I'm a newbie in Gradle and Groovy in general, and I'm trying to understand the following example from the [Gradle user guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec:deploying_to_a_maven_repository), and especially how I could find, in the DSL documentation, where all these options can be found:

```
uploadArchives {
    repositories.mavenDeployer {
        name = 'sshDeployer' // optional
        configuration = configurations.deployerJars
        repository(url: "scp://repos.mycompany.com/releases") {
            authentication(userName: "me", password: "myPassword")
        }
    }
}
```

What I understand:

- `uploadArchives` is a task of type `Upload`, added to the project by the Java plugin
- `repositories` is a property of the `Upload` task, of type `RepositoryHandler`

What I don't understand:

- `mavenDeployer` doesn't appear anywhere in the [documentation of RepositoryHandler](http://gradle.org/docs/1.2/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/dsl/RepositoryHandler.html). Where does it come from? How are we supposed to know that such a method exists?
- Searching in the index, I find that `mavenDeployer` is a method from [MavenRepositoryHandlerConvention](http://gradle.org/docs/1.2/javadoc/org/gradle/api/plugins/MavenRepositoryHandlerConvention.html#mavenDeployer%28groovy.lang.Closure%29) which is mixed in the RepositoryHandler associated with each task of type Upload. Too bad this isn't mentioned in `RepositoryHandler`'s documentation and Upload's documentation.
- Although it could be clearer, I understand that the closure must configure an object of type `GroovyMavenDeployer`. But reading the javadoc, the `repository` property for example is of type `Object`. How can I know that I can configure it using the following?

  ```
  repository(url: "scp://repos.mycompany.com/releases") {
      authentication(userName: "me", password: "myPassword")
  }
  ```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Gradle DSL documentation is not especially comprehensive. It's not always clear where public api stops and private impl starts & often the source code is the only place to get a comprehensive view (so I find it is generally easiest to link the src code to my IDE).

In your specific case, [the userguide](https://docs.gradle.org/1.3/userguide/userguide_single.html#deployerConfig) + the source code is the best way to navigate.

EDIT: this answer refers to an old version of gradle so the userguide link above points to that old version, current day (v7.4.2 at the time of writing) gradle uses a different plugin which is described in https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#publishing_maven

Comment: Which IDE do you use? I try to Cmd+click almost every key word in gradle.build in IDEA, but most of them are not resolved, eventually this becomes like walking in the dark.

Comment: I use intellij, I think code navigation/complete only works if the project is known as a gradle project to intellij. My build system uses the gradle idea plugin instead and, where a gradle installation is available, adds dependencies to link the project to that local install to provide src code access as well.

Comment: Even with this plugin many keywords are not resolved. E.g. with regards to this thread `repositories.mavenDeployer` is not resolved. Nevermind, hope it will get better ;)